# Wagtail-API: html_url does not include port

Tags: wagtail

I am passing the html_url through href. However, since it does not include the port 8000, the request is rejected (err: "localhost refused to connect.").

get-request: json

```
"items": [
     { "id": 3,
       "meta": { "type": "home.HomePage", 
                 "detail_url": "http://localhost/api/v2/pages/3/", 
                 "html_url": "http://localhost/", 
                 "slug": "home", 
                 "first_published_at": "2018-02-11T03:08:18.344199Z" 
        }, 
        "title": "Home" 
}]
```

Is there a way to include my port?

Comment: Have you filled in the port number in the Wagtail admin, under Settings -> Sites -> localhost?

Comment: I didn't know about that. That solved it, thank you!

Comment: Thanks @gasman! It solved my problem too!